# Suggestions for an implementation in Django

Tags: python-3.x, django, linux, iptables, python-iptables

I have a blog created on django and I need to configure the access using iptables.
I do not have any idea how to do it, anybody can indicate some material?
I was thinking about creating a function where it is possible to pass a range of ip numbers that are allowed to access, but I don't exactly where to do that in django.

Comment: What is the use of IPtables in that scenario?

Comment: @MohamedElKalioby The app I'm creating will work on a private server, it won't be open to the public. So the idea is that only specific ips can access it.

Comment: You can simply check the request headers if it matches certain ips.

Answer (score 0):

Then the best way is to create a middleware for that, it checks if the IP is in good range,

```
def checkIP(get_response):
   def middleware(request):
      x_forwarded_for = request.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')
      if x_forwarded_for:
         ip = x_forwarded_for.split(',')[0]
      else:
          ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
      if not ip in settings.GOOD_IPS:
           return HttpResponseForbidden("You are not allowed here")
      response = get_response(request)
      return response
return middleware
```

But generally, this is NOT a recommended behavior as IPs can change and the user could try to access from another terminal

Comment: I was thinking about using iptables. What do you think?

Comment: Surely it can be done, but middleware can give you more flexibility as checking the user as a superuser can access from anywhere, this can't be done by iptables

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate your suggestion and it solve my problem.

Comment: Try it and approve the answer if it works please